# Apply class to block on editor when the value of a custom control changes

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I'm new to Gutenberg blocks. I want to extend the core paragraph block and add a class depending on the value of a custom toggle control.

I have managed to do it and the class gets properly added on the front end, however, I also want the value to be reflected on the editor when the toggle changes.

This is the blockEdit code I'm using:

```
    const withToolbarControl = createHigherOrderComponent( ( BlockEdit ) => {
        return ( props ) => {

            // If current block is not allowed
            if ( ! enableToolbarButtonOnBlocks.includes( props.name ) ) {
                return (
                    <BlockEdit { ...props } />
                );
            }

            const { Fragment } = wp.element;

            const { attributes, setAttributes } = props;
            const { toggleval } = attributes;

            // Set the class names
            if ( toggleval === false ) {
                props.attributes.className = 'red';
            }
            else {
                props.attributes.className = 'blue';
            }

            // Add the toggle control
            return (
                <Fragment>
                    <BlockEdit { ...props } />
                    <InspectorControls key="visibility">
                        <PanelBody title={ __( 'Visibility' ) } >
                        <ToggleControl
                            label="Toggle"
                            checked={ toggleval }
                            onChange={ (value) => {
                                setAttributes( {
                                    toggleval: value
                                } );
                            } }
                        /> 
                        </PanelBody>
                    </InspectorControls>
                </Fragment>
            );

        };
    }, 'withToolbarControl' );

    wp.hooks.addFilter(
        'editor.BlockEdit',
        'custom-attributes/with-toolbar-control',
        withToolbarControl
    );
```

With this the classes get properly added to the editor's block too (I have a separate stylesheet for the admin and for the front end), however, the change doesn't take effect "on change". Instead, the block has to be manually re-selected and then the style is applied.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well done on your implementation of `withToolbarControl` - that's one of the harder aspects of building Gutenberg blocks with HOC. In this scenario though, there may be a simplier way...

If your goal is only to apply a CSS class of 'red' or 'blue' to the paragraph block, then [Block Styles](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-styles/) is perfect for this. Block Styles also handles rendering/previewing of the style live in the Editor, so you only need to register your styles for the paragraph block:

**JavaScript**

```js
wp.blocks.registerBlockStyle('core/paragraph', [
    {
        name: 'red',
        label: 'Red',
    },
    {
        name: 'blue',
        label: 'Blue',
    }
]);
```

There's no need for extending Edit or adding the toggle for adding styles unless your goal is far more complex/dependant on extra attributes.

**style.css**

```css
.is-style-red{
    color:red;
}

.is-style-blue{
    color:blue;
}
```

NB. *The `is-style-` prefix is added automatically to the name of the style you register*

**Result**
[image: Editor > Paragraph > Styles]